# Mailchimp gradient css background color

Tags: html, css, mailchimp

How to make a gradient color as my background in mailchimp using CSS? I tried to it with my current CSS but it doesn't work, but when using a background-color:*simple color like red or blue* it does work. Does mailchimp support gradient in CSS?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you. Here is my sample CSS code.

```
.gradient {
    height: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient( #982C2F, #565392);
    width: 600px;
    margin: auto;}
```

Comment: show full code ...

Comment: What browser are you using? might need -webkit and -moz prefix

Comment: I'm using google chrome @Webpandit

Comment: background-image: linear-gradient( #982C2F, #565392);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( #982C2F, #565392);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( #982C2F, #565392);
does this work, if not post your full code

Comment: css support is very limited in email clients: https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/.  Basically, try stick to css 2

Comment: I have tried to use the webkit-linear-gradient and etc. but it doesn't work. I have found out that gradient in emails is not really supported as mentioned by @Pete. Thank you guys for all of your help.